# Linker error OpenCV for SVM

Tags: opencv, linker, svm

I seem to have a linker problem on my code.

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "opencv/ml.h"
#include "opencv/cvaux.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include "opencv/cxcore.h"
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"

using namespace cv;
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
// Data for visual representation
    int width = 512, height = 512;
    Mat image = Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC3);

    // Set up training data
    float labels[4] = {1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0};
    Mat labelsMat(3, 1, CV_32FC1, labels);

    float trainingData[4][2] = { {501, 10}, {255, 10}, {501, 255}, {10, 501} };
    Mat trainingDataMat(3, 2, CV_32FC1, trainingData);

    // Set up SVM's parameters
    CvSVMParams params;
    params.svm_type    = CvSVM::C_SVC;
    params.kernel_type = CvSVM::LINEAR;
    params.term_crit   = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 100, 1e-6);

    // Train the SVM
    CvSVM SVM;
    SVM.train(trainingDataMat, labelsMat, Mat(), Mat(), params);

    Vec3b green(0,255,0), blue (255,0,0);
    // Show the decision regions given by the SVM
    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
        {
            Mat sampleMat = (Mat_<float>(1,2) << i,j);
            float response = SVM.predict(sampleMat);

            if (response == 1)
                image.at<Vec3b>(j, i)  = green;
            else if (response == -1) 
                 image.at<Vec3b>(j, i)  = blue;
        }

    // Show the training data
    int thickness = -1;
    int lineType = 8;
    circle( image, Point(501,  10), 5, Scalar(  0,   0,   0), thickness, lineType);
    circle( image, Point(255,  10), 5, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);
    circle( image, Point(501, 255), 5, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);
    circle( image, Point( 10, 501), 5, Scalar(255, 255, 255), thickness, lineType);

    // Show support vectors
    thickness = 2;
    lineType  = 8;
    int c     = SVM.get_support_vector_count();

    for (int i = 0; i < c; ++i)
    {
        const float* v = SVM.get_support_vector(i);
        circle( image,  Point( (int) v[0], (int) v[1]),   6,  Scalar(128, 128, 128), thickness, lineType);
    }

    imwrite("result.png", image);        // save the image 

    imshow("SVM Simple Example", image); // show it to the user
    waitKey(0);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the error report:

> 2>SVM.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void
>   __thiscall cv::Mat::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall
>   cv::Mat::release(void)" (?release@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ) 2>SVM.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall
>   cv::MatConstIterator::seek(int,bool)"
>   (?seek@MatConstIterator@cv@@QAEXH_N@Z) referenced in function "public:
>   class cv::MatConstIterator & __thiscall
>   cv::MatConstIterator::operator++(void)"
>   (??EMatConstIterator@cv@@QAEAAV01@XZ) 2>SVM.obj : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall
>   cv::Mat::copySize(class cv::Mat const &)"
>   (?copySize@Mat@cv@@QAEXABV12@@Z) referenced in function "public:
>   __thiscall cv::Mat::Mat(class cv::Mat const &)" (??0Mat@cv@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) 2>SVM.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol "void __cdecl cv::fastFree(void *)"
>   (?fastFree@cv@@YAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall
>   cv::Mat::~Mat(void)" (??1Mat@cv@@QAE@XZ) 2>SVM.obj : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall
>   cv::Mat::create(int,int const *,int)" (?create@Mat@cv@@QAEXHPBHH@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: void __thiscall
>   cv::Mat::create(int,int,int)" (?create@Mat@cv@@QAEXHHH@Z) 2>SVM.obj :
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall
>   cv::MatConstIterator::seek(int const *,bool)"
>   (?seek@MatConstIterator@cv@@QAEXPBH_N@Z) referenced in function
>   "public: __thiscall cv::MatConstIterator::MatConstIterator(class
>   cv::Mat const *)" (??0MatConstIterator@cv@@QAE@PBVMat@1@@Z) 2>SVM.obj
>   : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall
>   cv::Mat::convertTo(class cv::_OutputArray const
>   &,int,double,double)const "
>   (?convertTo@Mat@cv@@QBEXABV_OutputArray@2@HNN@Z) referenced in
>   function "public: class cv::Mat_ & _*thiscall
>   cv::Mat*::operator=(class cv::Mat const &)"
>   (??4?$Mat_@M@cv@@QAEAAV01@ABVMat@1@@Z) 2>SVM.obj : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(class cv::Mat &)"
>   (??0_OutputArray@cv@@QAE@AAVMat@1@@Z) referenced in function "public:
>   class cv::Mat_ & _*thiscall cv::Mat*::operator=(class
>   cv::Mat const &)" (??4?$Mat_@M@cv@@QAEAAV01@ABVMat@1@@Z) 2>SVM.obj :
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class cv::Mat
>   __thiscall cv::Mat::reshape(int,int,int const *)const " (?reshape@Mat@cv@@QBE?AV12@HHPBH@Z) referenced in function "public:
>   class cv::Mat_ & _*thiscall cv::Mat*::operator=(class
>   cv::Mat const &)" (??4?$Mat_@M@cv@@QAEAAV01@ABVMat@1@@Z) 2>SVM.obj :
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall
>   CvSVM::~CvSVM(void)" (??1CvSVM@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
>   2>SVM.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl
>   cv::waitKey(int)" (?waitKey@cv@@YAHH@Z) referenced in function _main
>   2>SVM.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   cv::imshow(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class
>   cv::_InputArray const &)"
>   (?imshow@cv@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV_InputArray@1@@Z)
>   referenced in function _main 2>SVM.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol "bool __cdecl cv::imwrite(class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > const &,class cv::_InputArray const &,class
>   std::vector > const &)"
>   (?imwrite@cv@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV_InputArray@1@ABV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@3@@Z)
>   referenced in function _main 2>SVM.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(class
>   cv::Mat const &)" (??0_InputArray@cv@@QAE@ABVMat@1@@Z) referenced in
>   function _main 2>SVM.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "public: virtual float const * __thiscall
>   CvSVM::get_support_vector(int)const "
>   (?get_support_vector@CvSVM@@UBEPBMH@Z) referenced in function _main
>   2>SVM.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual
>   int __thiscall CvSVM::get_support_vector_count(void)const "
>   (?get_support_vector_count@CvSVM@@UBEHXZ) referenced in function _main
>   2>SVM.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void _*cdecl
>   cv::circle(class cv::Mat &,class cv::Point*,int,class
>   cv::Scalar_ const &,int,int,int)"
>   (?circle@cv@@YAXAAVMat@1@V?$Point_@H@1@HABV?$Scalar_@N@1@HHH@Z)
>   referenced in function _main 2>SVM.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol "public: virtual float __thiscall CvSVM::predict(class
>   cv::Mat const &,bool)const " (?predict@CvSVM@@UBEMABVMat@cv@@_N@Z)
>   referenced in function _main 2>SVM.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall CvSVM::train(class
>   cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &,class cv::Mat const &,class
>   cv::Mat const &,struct CvSVMParams)"
>   (?train@CvSVM@@UAE_NABVMat@cv@@000UCvSVMParams@@@Z) referenced in
>   function _main 2>SVM.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "public: __thiscall CvSVM::CvSVM(void)" (??0CvSVM@@QAE@XZ) referenced
>   in function _main 2>SVM.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol "public: __thiscall CvSVMParams::CvSVMParams(void)"
>   (??0CvSVMParams@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main 2>SVM.obj :
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class
>   cv::MatExpr __cdecl cv::Mat::zeros(int,int,int)"
>   (?zeros@Mat@cv@@SA?AVMatExpr@2@HHH@Z) referenced in function _main

I have the last all-built version of OpenCV for Windows 7, available at WillowGarage, and I am trying to run this example from the wiki page: [link](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html). My compiler is VC++.

I have already seached on Google but I don't find anything working.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who would have the same problem, make sure you have ALL the right linker inputs (configuration -> linker -> inputs), included dlls such as opencv, highgui etc.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want a list of some of the inputs:

```
opencv_core412.lib
opencv_imgcodecs412.lib
opencv_imgproc412.lib
opencv_highgui412.lib
opencv_ml412.lib
opencv_video412.lib
opencv_features2d412.lib
opencv_calib3d412.lib
opencv_objdetect412.lib
opencv_flann412.lib
```

The 412 is the version and in this case as it is in Release mode it has no d at the end, otherwise it would be `opencv_flann412d.lib`